# Indexing big matrices with matfile function crashes matlab

Tags: matlab, memory, matrix

%   A,B,C,D,& E are all matrices of size (1500,1500,3500).

```
A  =  matfile('FileA.mat')
B  =  matfile('FileB.mat')
C  =  matfile('FileC.mat')
D  =  matfile('FileD.mat') 
E  =  matfile('FileE.mat')
```

% When I try to run the following code matlab crashes. I believe it's a memory problem.

```
SimilarIndex =       A.Matrix       >     5  ...
                   & B.Matrix       <     2  ...
                   & C.Matrix       >     4  ...
                   & D.Matrix       <     8  ...
                   & E.Matrix       <     1      ;
```

% Is there anyway to index these matrices in memory feasible way?

% Appreciate the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One matrix of size (1500*1500*3500) contains 7875000000 elements. If we assume that the matrix elements are single-precision floating point values we need 7875000000*32 bits or roughly 30 gigabytes of memory to store one matrix. Work with even one matrix of this size is possible, or if you have 64 gigabytes of memory(or more), or if the matrix is [sparse](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html).

Comment: I just need to run the code once.. so I used a combination of a large memory paging file on my hard drives and a sparsed solution. 

Thanks for your advice